# How to create two columns in an csv file from an for loop in python?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, for-loop

```
import json
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init(autoreset = False)
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options = chrome_options)
driver.minimize_window()

for b in range(500):

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    url = "https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Marriage%20%26%20Family%20Therapy&entityCode=PS303&where=CA&pageNum={}&sort.provider=bestmatch&state=CA".format(b+104)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"))
    for i in range(length):
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']")
        elements[i].click()
        handles = driver.window_handles
        driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
        time.sleep(1)
        print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h1").get_attribute("innerText"))
        print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='summary-standard-button-row-mobile']/a").get_attribute("innerText"))
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(handles[0])
        time.sleep(1)
```

The output of this code is like this:

```
Full Name
Phone Number
```

Is there a way so I can import the name and phone number in separate columns in a CSV file?

I've tried numerous ways but they sadly do not work because the for loop rewrites my rows in the CSV file.

Comment: What do you mean by *"rewrites my Index in the CSV file"?* CSV files don't have an index, they are just text files with a fixed number of columns and an arbitrary number of rows. In very brief, you write a CSV file with `with open(filename, 'w') as file: writer = csv.writer(file); for row in whatever: writer.writerow(whatever[0], whatever[1])`

Comment: I meant rows sorry

Comment: Then what does *"rewrites my rows"* mean? Just open once at the beginning and then write as many rows as you have records. Sounds vaguely like you opened a new file on each iteration, overwriting the old; but you are showing us an irrelevant piece of code instead of the one you were having trouble with.

Comment: Please review the guidance for including a [mre] when asking a question. We don't need to see your working code, we need to see the part which you are having trouble with; the less unrelated, distracting code, the more likely someone will read and answer (and for beginner questions, the more likely we can point you to an existing duplicate which ideally then also doesn't contain anything unrelated).

Comment: Tangentially, one such distraction: `PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"` is a syntax error with modern Python; you want `PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"` or double the backslashes, or replace them with forward slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
import csv

# ...

with open('phone.csv' 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for b in range(500):
        # ...
        for i in range(length):
            # ...
            name = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h1").get_attribute("innerText")
            phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='summary-standard-button-row-mobile']/a").get_attribute("innerText")
            writer.writerow([name, phone])
```